# Batch Rename Files in a Directory By Rearranging Filenames

Tags: powershell, file-rename

I have a large number of files in a directory with this type of naming convention: "[Date] [Lastname] 345.pdf". Note: the 345 is constant for all of them

I would like to rename all of the files so that they read "[Lastname] [Date] 345.pdf".

Edit: I had a typo in there initially

I have had some success with:

```
gci -Filter *.pdf| %{Rename-Item $_.fullname $_.Name.Split(" ")[1]}
```

But that only gives me "[Date].pdf".  Basically, I can't figure out how to use the above command to combine two different parts of the split.  I basically want "[1] [0] [2].pdf" if that makes any sense.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach, using regular expressions:

```
Get-ChildItem *.pdf | % {
  $newName = $_.Name -replace '^(.*) (\S+) (\S+\.pdf)$', '$2 $1 $3'
  Rename-Item $_ $newName
}
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `^(.*)` matches any number of characters at the beginning of the string and captures them in a group. `[Date]` in your example filename `[Date] [Lastname] 345.pdf`.
- `(\S+)` matches one or more consecutive non-whitespace characters and captures them in a second group. `[Lastname]` in your example filename `[Date] [Lastname] 345.pdf`.
- `(\S+\.pdf)$` matches one or more consecutive non-whitespace characters followed by the string `.pdf` at the end of the string and captures that in a third group. `345.pdf` in your example filename `[Date] [Lastname] 345.pdf`.

The groups are referred to by `$1`, `$2` and `$3`, so the replacement string `'$2 $1 $3'` re-orders the groups the way you want.

Comment: This worked! Thanks.  Can you explain exactly what's going on here?  Still trying to learn.

Comment: @user3194848 BTW, the question is ambiguous...the example in the beginning implies that you want to replace **345** with **302**, but what you say at the end implies that you want to keep the same number (which is what the regex in this answer does). Was the **302** a typo? If you really do want to change the number, change the replace to `$_.Name -replace '^(.*) (\S+) ([^.]+)', '$2 $1 302'`.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot.

```
gci *.pdf| %{
    $Name = $PSItem.Name.Split(' ');
    $Dest = ('{0} {1} {2}' -f $Name[1], $Name[0], $Name[2]);
    Move-Item $PSItem.FullName -Destination $Dest;
};
```

Comment: This one didn't work.  I got an error "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression" on the split operator.

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you using? `$PSItem` is new as of PowerShell version 3.0, so if you're running PowerShell version 2.0, then you'll have to use `$_` instead of `$PSItem`.